# How can I reindex a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, array-difference

I'm using this function to calculate the difference between 2 multi-dimensional arrays:

```
/**
 * http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#91756
 * @param $array1
 * @param $array2
 * @return array
 */

function arrayRecursiveDiff($array1, $array2){
    $aReturn = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
        if (array_key_exists($mKey, $array2)) {
            if (is_array($mValue)) {
                $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $array2[$mKey]);
                if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
            } else {
                if ($mValue != $array2[$mKey]) {
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
    }
    return $aReturn;
}
```

It works perfect, bar just one tiny issue:

```
array(2) {
  ["installed"]=>
  array(3) {
    [3]=>
    string(9) "somevalue1"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "somevalue2"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "somevalue3"        
  }
  ["backend"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["preload"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "somevalue4"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "somevalue5"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the sub array "installed" must be re-indexed. In fact I need to recursively reindex this array (or better yet, I need the arrayRecursiveDiff function to return a correctly indexed array). I have tried different ways but seem like my brain is fried for now!

Comment: Can you post data you're sending to the function ?

Comment: sure, here is the sample code: http://codepad.org/1uFqzhJ0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this function will solve your issue

```
var_dump(array_map("array_values",arrayRecursiveDiff($a,$b)));
```

Edit:
This one keeps non-digit indexes:

```
var_dump(array_map(create_function('$x','$k = key($x); return (is_numeric($k)) ? array_values($x) : $x;'),$aDiff));
```

Note that this function only works for level 2 array-reindex.

Comment: Thank you, that works quite nice, http://codepad.org/XHLtR9WU

I'm trying to figure out the way to do it recursively to support more than 1 level, will post back here

Comment: Okie, so using your example this seems to work for me for multi-dim array. I used more than 1 func but I think it's okie because the others are also useful and can be used at other places in my code as well: http://codepad.org/76TEonav

Comment: Great, don't forget to set this (or yours) answer as accepted

Comment: I accepted your answer, much appreciated your kind help. Regards

Answer (score 0):

try this. sort function will help you

```
 $array = array (
  "installed"=>
  array (     
    3 =>     "somevalue1",
    4 =>     "somevalue2",
    5 =>     "somevalue3"
  ),
  "backend"=>
  array (
    "preload"=>
    array(
      0=>
      "somevalue4",
      1=>
      "somevalue5"
    )
  )
);
var_dump($array);
sort($array['installed']);
var_dump($array);
```

loop through variable and use sort that will help you recursively.

```
foreach($array as $tmparray){
   $newArray = sort($tmparray);
var_dump($newArray);
}
```

Comment: so if I need to do this for multi dimension array I will need to do it recursively right? Thank you, seem like the way to go if I can't fix the array diff function to return my expected result. Just a bit more performance overhead I will have to take if there is no other way.

Answer (score -3):

You can re-index an array like this: `$arr = array_values($arr);`

I would post the code to re-index recursively, but it's not really hard, you should try it yourself and then post the code here.

Comment: sound like an option, how should I check if the current sub-array is associative or not? (if associative, I dont want to use array_values or I will break it). Or maybe I should just use sort? I may not want to sort if it's an associative array tho (by associative, I mean at least 1 of the key is a string, not integer)