# Reindex multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'd like to re-index a multidimensional array to be like this:

```
[
    0 => ['id' => 1, 'children' => [['id' => 2], ['id' => 3]]],
    4 => ['id' => 5, 'children' => [['id' => 6], ['id' => 7]]]
    8 => ...
]
```

If I use `array_walk_recursive` I get:

```
[
    0 => ['id' => 1, 'children' => [['id' => 2], ['id' => 3]]],
    1 => ['id' => 4, 'children' => [['id' => 5], ['id' => 6]]]
    2 => ...
]
```

This is almost there, but not quite...

```
array_walk_recursive($out, function(&$item, $key) {
        if($key == 'id')
        {
            $item = $this->_i;
            $this->_i++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reindex a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091824/how-can-i-reindex-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: not really, I have a single array, and also up to 3 levels

Comment: can you add the php arrays?

Comment: Can you post your code to evaluate it?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this, it not pretty (I later found that the problem was elsewhere and left the code in an proof of concept state). Posting this if anyone else need this kind of structure.

```
// restructure the array for reindexing
$out = [];
$k = 0;
foreach ($arr as $as) 
{
    $test = ['id' => $k, 'items' => $as];

    array_push($out, $test);
    $k++;
}

// reindex multidimensiona array
$i = 1;
array_walk_recursive($out, function(&$item, $key) {
    global $i;

    if($key == 'id')
    {
        $item = $i;
        $i++;
    }

});

// final array restructuring 
$res = [];
foreach($out as $oo)
{
    $firstKey = array_key_first($oo);
    $res[$oo[$firstKey]] = $oo['items'];
}

var_dump( $res );
```